# Limiting Sign in with Google to Google Workspace (Previously G Suite) users

Tags: google-oauth, supabase

Our application has Sign In with Google setup via [Supabase](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/auth-google). We want users to be able to sign up themselves, but want to limit it to users using Google Workspace and have custom domain rather than Gmail.

Went through Google 0Auth / Cloud Platform Documentation, wasn't able to find any configuration. Is there a direct way of doing this without custom logic? If we were to do it via code, is it as straightforward checking for `gmail.com` on the email or is there any metadata from Google Profile we can use?

Comment: You can subscribe to changes in the [users table](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/FZ7XWXVXEAAlc1C?format=jpg&name=medium) and make a trigger to send an email/ call a POSTGRES function. Then send an email to the user informing they need to use a workspace account. You can even "auto drop" the row if you detect regular gmail account, but it is good to email warn the users still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

Create a new function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION
  public.check_user_domain()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS
  $$
  BEGIN
    IF NEW.email LIKE '%@gmail.com' THEN
      raise exception 'INCORRECT_DOMAIN';
    END IF;

    RETURN NEW;
  END;
  $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql SECURITY DEFINER;
```

Create a new trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER
  check_user_domain_trigger
  before INSERT ON auth.users
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE
    public.check_user_domain();
```

I recorded a short video of how it works on Youtube:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C-HoRO7Wrhg